# Angular ValueProvider and Injector literals used in component and module providers declaration

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm providing some constans values via `ValueProvider`, and I'm little bit surprised with semantic differences between `ClassProvider` & `ValueProvider`.

My current ValueProvider looks following:

Provider definition:

```
export const DeliveryChangeTextToken = new InjectionToken<DeliveryTextsAndConditionsIfc[]>('Provides text option values for delivery component');

export const DELIVERY_CHANGE_TEXT_PROVIDER: ValueProvider = {
    provide: DeliveryChangeTextToken,
    useValue: /* Here is object literal or imported value, whatever */
}
```

Now inside a module, I'm adding new provider to providers array:

```
providers: [DELIVERY_CHANGE_TEXT_PROVIDER]
```

And I'm using it into component like so:

```
constructor(@Inject(DeliveryChangeTextToken) texts: DeliveryTextsAndConditionsIfc[])
{ this.specialTxtConditions = texts; }
```

It works and it's fine but I'm worried a bit with those `Provider` array and constructor `@Inject` shapes.

Module declaration uses `Provider[]` form, which is provider literal composed of `provide`, `useValue` and `multi` sob fields, all enclosed under `DELIVERY_CHANGE_TEXT_PROVIDER`. Simple and elegant.

But to access it within component, it has to be provided with `@Inject()`, which accepts token type, in my case it's `DeliveryChangeTextToken`.

This is kinda confusing and requires to navigate between 3 files to see what value under what token is actually provided and is standing in contrast with how `ClassProvider`, most common provider is used under same name every time in code:

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Service{}
```

Module:

```
provide: [Service]
```

Component:

```
constructor(private service: Service)
```

Is there any way to ensure consistence among provider declaration and actual DI injection semantics?

And maybe bonus question, what kind of magic `@Injectable()` is actually doing to make it so slick for `ClassProvider`s to work?

EDIT:
Unfolding provider object literal, of course is option, to ensure sam form in both places, but I'm rather would like to use shorter Provider form in both places than longer, bloated form of provider literal:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: DeliveryChangeTextToken, useValue: /* Here is object literal or imported value, whatever */
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. I'm glad you brought it out.

In order to achieve consistency in such cases, IMO, you can use an **abstract class** to define the shape of an object. This will also allow you to get rid of the `@Inject` decorator.

```js
export abstract class CurrentUser {
  role: string;
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

```js
const currentUserLiteral: CurrentUser = {
  id: '123',
  name: 'andrei',
  role: 'admin',
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CurrentUser,
      useValue: currentUserLiteral,
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
@Component({
   /* ... */
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (
    private crtUser: CurrentUser,
  ) {
    console.log(crtUser.name); // 'andrei'
  }
}
```

`crtUser` will get the right types as well.

AFAIK, `@Injectable()` shines when your class injects other dependencies as well.

If your class does not have any, you are free to avoid it, even though it's recommended you always use it.

```js
// Does not have any injected dependencies!
export class InjectableWithoutDecorator {
  private name = 'andrei';

  constructor () { }

  getNameUpperCase () {
    return this.name.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  /* ... */
  providers: [
    InjectableWithoutDecorator,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
@Component({
  /* ... */
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (
    private withoutDecorator: InjectableWithoutDecorator,
  ) {
    console.log(withoutDecorator.getNameUpperCase()); // 'ANDREI'
  }
}
```

---

You cannot use an abstract class like this

```js
@NgModule({
  /* ... */
  providers: [AbstractClass]
})
```

because **abstract classes** are **not instantiatable** on their own. They can be used through their subclasses.

[ng-run playground](https://ng-run.com/edit/dxDx2W2s42ylXeJXn7TR?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Seems elegant! But still, you need to provide provider in your NgModule in form of literal instead of just Class name. Seems this have something to do with constructor that is present in classes and can be invoked by using only class name (like factory provider kind of...) versus object literal which does not have such and has to be pionted directly. Thank you for contribution!

Comment: Oh, apparently I forgot about this. There is a way to provide, for example, an InjectionToken without manually specifying it inside any module. Have a look, the injectiontoken constructor can have a second argument which is an object: { providedIn: ‘root’, useFactory: () => yourObjectLiteral }. As if it wasn’t awesome enough, you have the same possibilities(even more) for @Injectable!

Comment: Also, by doing things this way, you make your providers tree-shakable.